# How to get the source code of a file where an object is created?

Tags: python, reflection, module

In my `main.py` I have the following Python code:

```
from tasks import SimpleTask
from reflectors import Reflector

task = SimpleTask()

source_code = Reflector().get_source_code(task)
```

I want to get the source code of `main.py` from inside the `Reflector.get_source_code()` using only the parameter `task` passed.

If I do the following in `Reflector.get_source_code()` using Python's `inspect` module:

```
def get_source_code(self, task):
  return str(inspect.getsource(inspect.getmodule(task)))
```

I get the source code of `tasks` module where `SimpleTask` class is defined.

However, I want to get source code of main.py (the file where `task` object is created).

I have managed to do the following:

```
source_code = Reflector().get_source_code(lambda: task)

def run(self, task_callback):
  source_code = str(inspect.getsource(inspect.getmodule(task_callback)))
```

However, I don't like the **`lambda: task`** syntax.

Is there any way to achieve this without the lambda hack?

Comment: Not quite sure, what's wrong with this syntax, but you can try to apply [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: Could you provide me an example? I don't get how I could use it. So, you think it is not possible to get the ```main.py``` source code from the object ```task``` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "source code of `main.py`"? It's is a filename and doesn't have "source code".

Comment: I mean the contents of the file.